# Returning specific content

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need only the ip addresses. How to scrap that. My code right now-

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

x = urllib.request.urlopen('http://bannedhackersips.blogspot.com/2014_08_04_archive.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(x,"html.parser")
data = soup.find_all("ul", {"class": "posts"})

for content in data:
   print(content.text)
```

Output:

```
[Fail2Ban] SSH: banned 116.10.191.162
[Fail2Ban] SSH: banned 116.10.191.204
[Fail2Ban] SSH: banned 61.174.51.232
[Fail2Ban] SSH: banned 61.174.51.224
[Fail2Ban] SSH: banned 116.10.191.225
[Fail2Ban] SSH: banned 200.162.47.130
[Fail2Ban] SSH: banned 116.10.191.175
[Fail2Ban] SSH: banned 61.174.51.223
[Fail2Ban] SSH: banned 61.174.51.234
[Fail2Ban] SSH: banned 61.174.51.209
[Fail2Ban] SSH: banned 116.10.191.165
[Fail2Ban] SSH: banned 106.240.247.220
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract from the text with a regex:

```
data = soup.find("ul", {"class": "posts"})

import re

r = re.compile("\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+")

print(r.findall(data.text))
['116.10.191.162', '116.10.191.204', '61.174.51.232', '61.174.51.224', '116.10.191.225', '200.162.47.130', '116.10.191.175', '61.174.51.223', '61.174.51.234', '61.174.51.209', '116.10.191.165', '106.240.247.220']
```

Or as the pattern repeats you can split into substrings with splitlines and split once from the end of each substring to extract the ip:

```
data = soup.find("ul", {"class": "posts"})

ips = [line.rsplit(None, 1)[1] for line in data.text.splitlines() if line]

print(ips)
['116.10.191.162', '116.10.191.204', '61.174.51.232', '61.174.51.224', '116.10.191.225', '200.162.47.130', '116.10.191.175', '61.174.51.223', '61.174.51.234', '61.174.51.209', '116.10.191.165', '106.240.247.220']
```

There is only one `posts` class on the page so find is sufficient, when you iterate over `find_all` you are actually iterating over a single element list.